# Trying to get property of non-object in uselogin.php

Tags: php, laravel

Hi im using larave but this the code  and line     `if(is_null($StudentId)) $StudentId = Auth::user()->students_ID`; results in trying to get property of non object  error

```
namespace App\Models;


use App\Core\Actions;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserLog extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['student_id','action','time'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public static function Log($Action,$StudentId = null) {
       if(is_null($StudentId)) $StudentId = Auth::user()->students_ID;

        if(self::CheckLastMinute($Action,$StudentId)) return;
        self::create([
            'student_id' => $StudentId,
            'action' => $Action,
            'time' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
        ]);
    }

    public static function CheckLastMinute($Action,$StudentId = null) {
        if(is_null($StudentId)) $StudentId = Auth::user()->students_ID;
        return self::where('action',$Action)
            ->where('student_id',$StudentId)
            ->where('time','>=',Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1)->toDateTimeString())
            ->count();
    }
}
```

terribly sorry the missing parts had no idea im having a really bad slow connection today

Comment: you didn't provide enough code to answer. Please improve your question by adding the controller and the model you are using...

Comment: namespace App\Models; use App\Core\Actions; use Carbon\Carbon; use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Comment: please click edit and add the code to the question not in the comments

Comment: looks like you need to read a guide on how to post before posting lol the post is very unclear, and your code is obfuscated. No one can help you with this amount of information.

Comment: added the code,.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to assume you have an authenticated user instance.

When you don't have an authenticated user, either in a cli context or a guest browsing your site, `Auth::user()` will return null.  So you're essentially calling `null->students_ID` in those contexts which is the reason for the error.